# Convert a pointer to an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-mapping

The CreateFileMapping function returns a pointer to a memory mapped file, and I want to treat that memory mapping as an array.

Here's what I basically want to do:

```
char Array[] = (char*) CreateFileMapping(...);
```

Except apparently I can't simply wave my arms and declare that a pointer is now an array.

Do you guys have any idea how I can do this?  I don't want to copy the the values the pointer is pointing to into the array because that will use too much memory with large files.

Thanks a bunch,

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You do not need to. You can index a pointer as if it was an array:

```
char* p = (char*)CreateFileMapping(...);
p[123] = 'x';
...
```

Comment: Note that calling sizeof() on an array and a pointer will return different values. The pointer will return the size of a pointer, not the array. This means you will need to send along the size of the array instead of doing the array length trick. You could create a true pointer-to-an-array by doing `char (*p)[] = ...` and then get the members using `(*p)[123] = 'x';` Then you could still get the size without passing it along.

Answer (score 5):

In C/C++, pointers and arrays are not the same thing.

But in your case, for your purposes they are.

You have a pointer.

You can give it a subscript.

E.g. a char* pointer points to the start of "hello"

pointer[0] is the first character 'h'

pointer[1] is the second character 'e'

So just treat it as you are thinking about an array.

Comment: To the language, pointers and arrays are the same thing.  An array is a pointer to the first object in a series.

Comment: @dnh828, you're wrong. Try using `sizeof` on an array and a pointer of the "same" type. Or assign one array to another. A pointer to array is also distinct from pointer to pointer. And so on.

Comment: To be more specific, in C/C++, arrays _decay_ to pointers _in certain contexts_. Not always.

Comment: a point and an array are most definitely not the same thing in C/C++. Just because an array is able to decay into a pointer doesn't make them the same.

Comment: And the reason that an array is different is *exactly* that the compiler knows how big it is (or at least how big it is in D-1 dimensions).

Answer (score 2):

"In C/C++, pointers and arrays are not the same thing." is true, but, the variable name for the array is the same as a pointer const (this is from my old Coriolis C++ Black Book as I recall).  To wit:

```
char carray[5];
char caarray2[5];
char* const cpc = carray;    //can change contents pointed to, but not where it points

/*
  cpc = carray2;    //NO!! compile error
  carray = carray2; //NO!! compile error - same issue, different error message
*/

cpc[3] = 'a';  //OK of course, why not.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: cpc[3] = 'a'; will give an error.. is it possible to make the pointer to point to another address..

Answer (score 1):

But how's pointer different from array? What's wrong with

> `char *Array = (char*)CreateFileMapping(...);`

You can treat the `Array` more or less like you would treat an array from now on.

Comment: There is a difference. An array can have sizeof() called on it, but a pointer will return the sizeof the pointer, not the array. Therefore the length of the target data chunk in memory is not retrievable from a pointer to an array. Unfortunately there is no way to convert the pointer to an array into a true array without the size of said array, but then you won't need to convert it anymore...

Comment: @user1884803, yeah, the question was not what's the difference between array and pointer, but what would be the difference in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a C-style cast:

```
char *p = (char*)CreateFileMapping(...);
p[123] = 'x';
```

Or the preferred reinterpret cast:

```
char *p std::reinterpret_cast<char*>(CreateFileMapping(...));
p[123] = 'x';
```

Answer (score -2):

I was also searching for this answer. What you need to do is to create your own type of array.

```
    static const int TickerSize = 1000000;
    int TickerCount;
    typedef char TickerVectorDef[TickerSize];
```

You can also cast your pointer into this new type. Otherwise you get "Compiler error C2440". It has to be a fixed size array though. If you only use it as a pointer, no actual memory is allocated (except 4-8 bytes for the pointer itself).