# How to convert a char* to a char[]

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I was wondering if there was a way to convert a string that has its first letter pointed at by a char* to a char[], so it is no longer a pointer, but a literal char[].

For example, if my string is "hi my name is bob\0", and `char* pointer` had this string copied to it via memcpy, is there a way to turn this back to a char[]?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well... why isn't it good enough as-is? I feel this is an XY problem.

Comment: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Yes, definitely feels like that.

Comment: @H2CO3 The "string" actually starts out as a jbyteArray, which I have to convert to a jbyte*, and eventually a char*. I've been having issues with memory corruption though so I am changing the pointers where the error occurs to character arrays. This could be a naive solution, but it was the first thing to come to mind :)

Comment: You're missing a language tag. You said jByteArray, so I presume it's [tag:jni], then either [tag:c] or [tag:c++].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
#define STRLEN (64)
char greeting[STRLEN];

strncpy(greeting,chrptr,STRLEN);

if (strlen(chrptr) > (STRLEN-1))
   greeting[(STRLEN-1)] = 0;
```

Comment: yes! exactly like this. I have a question though. The strcpy reference says strcpy should be defined like this `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );` Why does char* destination not have to be a pointer in this case?

Comment: <sigh>   fixed for the pedantic types.

Comment: Both strcpy and strncpy return the destination pointer for your convenience.  The greeting array IS like a char * in this case.  C considers them equivalent in this circumstance.  (Yes, I know arrays and pointers are not EXACTLY the same....)

Comment: @jim Well played :) The terminology is that arrays decay into/implicitly converted to a pointer when passed to a function.

Answer (score 3):

there is no need to convert, You can index a pointer as if it was an array. you can just to

```
char * a;
```

ant then do

```
char ch = a[4];
```

here is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309129/convert-a-pointer-to-an-array-in-c)

ther other way is also as easy

```
void f(int* p);

int x[5];
f(x);     // this is the same as f(&x[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same thing.  a[i] is equivalent to *(a + i), so much so that you can write i[a] and get the same result!

Comment: However, they are ***not*** the same thing: [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use strncpy or strcpy:

```
char *a = "hello world!";
int aLen = strlen(a);
char b[] = new char[aLen + 1]; // C++ version
// char* b = (char*)malloc((aLen + 1) * sizeof(char)); // C version
strncpy(b, a, aLen);
b[aLen] = '\0';
```

Comment: Would be worth adding a note stating that `malloc()` is to be used instead of `new` if we want a C solution.